# Eclipse, ClearCase and Automatic Checkout

Tags: eclipse, checkout, clearcase

In my Window->Preferences->ClearCase->Source Management, under

> Automatically checkout resources if necessary

I have set the option (out of the options Always, Never, Prompt)

> Never

However, if I were to have clicked inside an open file that had not been checked out, and accidentally enter a key, I still get prompted for whether I want the file to be checked out.

My understanding was that if I had selected the option

> Never

I could be sure that the file would neither be checked out, nor would I be prompted for the file to be checked out, under such circumstances wherein I accidentally enter a keystroke while the cursor is placed inside a file, which has not been checked out.

So, why is it that I am still being prompted about whether I want the file to be checked out?

Answer (score 0):

May be the Eclipse ClearCase plugin (the old "[Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter (For Eclipse)](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/rational-clearcase-scm-adapter-eclipse-version-7620)") is not supported by your current version of Eclipse and ClearCase.

> I am using a dynamic view

Try and see if the issue persists with a snapshot view (therefore working with files on a *local* disk, as opposed to a MVFS dynamic view)

[image: preferences]

You might need to switch to a CTE for instance (Cleartool Team Explorer) for ClearCase related operation, while working with snapshot views on Eclipse.

Comment: I am using a dynamic view.

Comment: @Vinod Which is why I mention a snapshot view, easier to work with with any IDE, including Eclipse: it is recommended when developing or simply compiling an existing codebase.

Answer (score 0):

The ClearTeam explorer integration does not have that preference path. There are two other integrations out there:

1. The (unsupported) SCM Adapter
2. An open source third-party integration at https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-ccase/

It looks like you're using #2 if that is your preference path. (Looked at the screenshots.) That adapter is relatively-recently updated and has a forum at https://sourceforge.net/p/eclipse-ccase/discussion/167189/thread/4d731445/

My recollection is that the CTE integration cedes this control over to the Eclipse session it's plugged into. It's possible that the other plugins do as well. It would make sense to do so since ClearCase can't know about every modelling/"zero code"/whatever tool that uses Eclipse. So it literally can't make that decision for you.